# XBOX ONE S Screen

Tags: monitors

i am going to buy an Xbox One S next week. Now i found myself searching for a new screen. I prefer screens smaller than 30". Since the XBOX ONE S supports 4k resolution i want to buy a screen with that resolution. My day long google serach didnt result in any good screens. So i am asking you: 
Do you know about good 4k gaming screens? 
Do you know about 4k gaming screens, smaller than 30" that support HDR?

Comment: Does price matter to you here (and if so, how much are you willing to spend)? Do you want any other fancy features besides HDR and 4K?

Comment: I just wanted to say; if you are only planning on using your XBOX One for gaming, there isn't much point in getting a 4K monitor. Most XBOX One games run only about 30fps at 900p, way below the resolution of a 4K monitor. Of couse, if you are using the XBOX for media streaming or video playback, then a 4K monitor may be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for sub 30" 4k UHD displays, TVs are all above 30" from what I have been able to find.

there are plenty of gaming PC monitors in the 4k UHD realm though.
I usually stick with Asus products, though everyone has their particular favorite manufacturers.

If I were going to upgrade to 4k using a less than 30" screen, I would go with this, though it is currently out of my price range:  [example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16824236677)

Would like to add that I am in no way affiliated with the computer industry, and am not remunerated for recommending any brand.